# login to website and request page with python request

Tags: session, python-requests

I know this has been asked a lot, and I would say ive done quite some searching, but I still cant crack this nut.

Im developing a script that imports my workschedule and notifies me when there' are changes made. For this I need to login to the schedule website and request my monthly schedule.

In several topics here like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995078/login-to-website-using-python-requests-module), it makes use of the requests.Session() function to keep the session alive, and they all seem to work for everyone, just not for me on this website..

Here's what I got:

```
import requests

baseurl = 'http://sum-it.nl/rooster/index.php'
username = 'front.last@email.com'
password = 'welcome123'

payload = {
    'rosEmail': username,
    'password': password
}

with requests.Session() as c:
    homepage = c.post(baseurl, payload)
    # homepage = c.post(baseurl + '?action=pub.sin', payload)
    securepage = c.get(baseurl + '?action=mef&functionId=17000&yearMonth=201706')
    if homepage.text == securepage.text:
        print('same content')
    else:
        print(securepage.text)
```

Whatever I do, I keep getting the same content: the login page (homepage.text).
Ive managed to login to the first page after logging in by 
using http://sum-it.nl/rooster/index.php?action=pub.sin&rosEmail=front.last@email.com&password=welcome123
as url to retrieve, but once I try to request a secured page after that (e.g the previous month schedule), it redirects me to the login page, even if I've requested the full link like above within the requests.Session() block.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forget the to include the 'action' key in `payload`

Comment: I believe I tried that in the commented out line. I've tried to add '?action=pub.sin' to the url sending it with the payload like above. That didnt work, so i tried what you mentioned. I added 'action': 'pub.sin' to the payload, but it still doesnt retrieve the right page (neither logs in),
payload = {
    'rosEmail': username,
    'password': password,
    'action': 'pub.sin'
}

Comment: Have you tried with 'User-Agent' in `headers` ?

Comment: I don't know why my other comment isn't here (I posted an update saying it works), but with I got it working with your help. I did several attempts to achieve the right page, and some left-over code from a previous attempt caused issues with the new code. Once I included 'action':'pub.sin' in the payload, I was able to retrieve every secured page after that. Thanks for the assist!